# How to use xsl:template at mid position of the XSLT1.0?

Tags: html, xml, xslt, xhtml

I am using this in upper head of my Template in my XSLT1.0 for getting different data values from xml.

complete code :- https://www.dropbox.com/s/6jollabe8tbbd7j/code.xslt?dl=0
 use this chunk at:- line no 745

And I have to use this chunk in mid of my xslt but how to do tha.t If I am using this I  am getting exception as xsl:template is not allowed in this position in the stylesheet!
How to Resolve that Any suggestion is appreciated

```
<xsl:template match="COMBINED-PAYMENT-HISTORY">
    <xsl:variable name="items-rtf">
        <xsl:call-template name="tokenize">
            <xsl:with-param name="text" select="normalize-space(.)"/>
        </xsl:call-template>
    </xsl:variable>
    <xsl:variable name="items" select="exsl:node-set($items-rtf)/item" /> 
<table>
    <!-- month -->
    <tr>
        <xsl:for-each select="$items">
            <td>
                <xsl:value-of select="substring-before(., ':')" />
            </td>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </tr>
    <!-- year -->
    <tr>
        <xsl:for-each select="$items">

            <td>
                <xsl:value-of select="substring-before(substring-after(., ':'), ',')" />
            </td>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </tr>
    <!-- data -->
    <tr>
        <xsl:for-each select="$items">
            <td>
                <xsl:value-of select="substring-after(., ',')" />
            </td>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </tr>
</table>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template name="tokenize">
    <xsl:param name="text" />
    <xsl:param name="delimiter" select="'|'" />
    <xsl:variable name="token" select="substring-before($text, $delimiter)" />
    <item>
        <xsl:value-of select="$token" />
    </item>
    <xsl:variable name="next" select="substring-after($text, $delimiter)" />
    <xsl:if test="$next">
        <!-- recursive call -->
        <xsl:call-template name="tokenize">
            <xsl:with-param name="text" select="$next" />
        </xsl:call-template>
    </xsl:if> 
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Please post minimal but complete samples that allow us to reproduce the exact error message you should also post. `xsl:template` has to be a top-level element of `xsl:stylesheet` so put both those templates at the top level. To use those template elsewhere, you would use `xsl:call-template` for the named template and `xsl:apply-templates` for the template with the `match` attribute, how exactly depends obviously on the XML structure of the input.

Comment: You haven't told us what you are trying to achieve (what is your input, what is your desired output). You've told us that you tried something and it didn't work because the language doesn't allow it, but unless we know what you want to achieve we can't tell you how to achieve it.